# How to extract the ndk abi filter library code in android?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to extract the code of native ndk library from the given java code. By analyzing the given java code can you guess what will be libcore.so file?

```
public abstract class CPU {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("core");
}

public static native int getCheckRes(Context context, int i);

public static native String getClock(Context context, byte[] bArr, int i);

public static native String getMagic(Context context, int i);

public static synchronized String getClockData(Context context, byte[] bArr, int i) {
    String clock;
    synchronized (CPU.class) {
        clock = getClock(context, bArr, i);
    }
    return clock;
}
}
```

I want to get the result of this method using only java or by using System.loadLibrary("core") given in the above code. I actually want the result of this code block in java without using any ndk library.

```
public static synchronized String getClockData(Context context, byte[] bArr, int i) {
    String clock;
    synchronized (CPU.class) {
        clock = getClock(context, bArr, i);
    }
    return clock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own version of "getClock()" doing "same" things that C/C++ code does in NDK library. It's possibile if you have library source code.

Comment: I have the libcore.so file but its encoded in utf-8, whats the solution?

Comment: An unix shared library is COMPILED so there isn't any easy way to know how it works under the hood. You could disassemble it but Assembler code is very difficult. If you don't have Source Code, there isn't any way.